# Parsing a list of objects with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I want to use Jackson to parse a list of objects. With Gson, I can do this easily:

```
List<MyType> list = new Gson().fromJson(input, Types.listOf(MyType.class));
```

With Jackson, it seems to be more difficult:

```
List<MyType> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, /* What to put here? */);
```

The code needs to work for lists of any type (like Gson does), so I can't just make a type that contains a list of `MyType` and pass that in.

I've tried using `new TypeLiteral<List<MyType>>(){}`, which works, but only for a single type. If I pass in the type to the method, it doesn't work any more:

```
public <T> List<T> parse(Class<T> myType) {
    // returns a List<Map<?,?>> instead of List<T>
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, new TypeLiteral<List<T>>(){});
}
```

How do I do this with Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with Jackson 2.7 and higher. It doesn't use the deprecated static methods to get the TypeFactory. Instead, it gets the TypeFactory from the object mapper.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.readValue(input, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyType.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is more easy

```
MyType myType = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, new TypeReference<List<MyType>>() {});
```

updated answer.

Comment: No, the input contains a *list of* `MyType`, not a single object.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution in the mean time. Apparently, Jackson provides its own way of working around this:

```
List<MyType> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, CollectionType.construct(List.class, SimpleType.construct(MyType.class));
```

Comment: Both construct() methods are deprecated since Jackson 2.7.

Comment: Gee, a 9 year old answer is out of date? Who would've guessed.