# Converting Json File to Java Objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to transform a json file to an array of objects with its information using jackson and Java. The Json File is

```
{"items":[{"id":"tt0111161","rank":"1","title":"The Shawshank Redemption","fullTitle":"The Shawshank Redemption (1994)","year":"1994","image":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDFkYTc0MGEtZmNhMC00ZDIzLWFmNTEtODM1ZmRlYWMwMWFmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_UX128_CR0,12,128,176_AL_.jpg","crew":"Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman","imDbRating":"9.2","imDbRatingCount":"2619254"},{"id":"tt0068646","rank":"2","title":"The Godfather","fullTitle":"The Godfather (1972)","year":"1972","image":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_UX128_CR0,12,128,176_AL_.jpg","crew":"Francis Ford Coppola (dir.), Marlon Brando, Al Pacino","imDbRating":"9.2","imDbRatingCount":"1813829"},....
```

My code is like this:

```
final var json= top150Json;
final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final var movies = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Movie>() {});
```

The movie Class is like this:

```
public class Movie {

private String id;
private int rank;
private String title;
private String fullTitle;
private int year;
private String image;
private String crew;
private int imDbRating;
private int imdDRatingCount;

public Movie() {
    this.id=null;
    this.rank= -1;
    this.title=null;
    this.fullTitle=null;
    this.year = 0;
    this.image =null;
    this.crew=null;
    this.imDbRating =0;
    this.imdDRatingCount =-1;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getFullTitle() {
    return fullTitle;
}

public void setFullTitle(String fullTitle) {
    this.fullTitle = fullTitle;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getCrew() {
    return crew;
}

public void setCrew(String crew) {
    this.crew = crew;
}

public int getImDbRating() {
    return imDbRating;
}

public void setImDbRating(int imDbRating) {
    this.imDbRating = imDbRating;
}

public int getImdDRatingCount() {
    return imdDRatingCount;
}

public void setImdDRatingCount(int imdDRatingCount) {
    this.imdDRatingCount = imdDRatingCount;
}
```

}

I get several errors and I think I have to parse only movies from the JSON file, that are inside the items and get something like this:

```
{"id":"tt0111161","rank":"1","title":"The Shawshank Redemption","fullTitle":"The Shawshank Redemption (1994)","year":"1994","image":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDFkYTc0MGEtZmNhMC00ZDIzLWFmNTEtODM1ZmRlYWMwMWFmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_UX128_CR0,12,128,176_AL_.jpg","crew":"Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman","imDbRating":"9.2","imDbRatingCount":"2619254"},{"id":"tt0068646","rank":"2","title":"The Godfather","fullTitle":"The Godfather (1972)","year":"1972","image":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_UX128_CR0,12,128,176_AL_.jpg","crew":"Francis Ford Coppola (dir.), Marlon Brando, Al Pacino","imDbRating":"9.2","imDbRatingCount":"1813829"},....
```

Someone know how to do it?

the errors I get are below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "items" (class Movie), not marked as ignorable (9 known properties: "crew", "title", "fullTitle", "id", "rank", "year", "imdDRatingCount", "imDbRating", "image"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: Movie["items"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:2023)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1700)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3612)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

I checked the duplicated problem and  tried

```
 List<Movie> movies = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, CollectionType.construct(List.class,SimpleType.construct(Movie.class)));
```

and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Movie>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
```

Comment: can I see the Movie class?

Comment: The JSON is a  list of type `Movie`?

Comment: @Albert, you have list of `Movie` &  you might need to define `items` in another class which can hold these list of `Movie`

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305341/parsing-a-list-of-objects-with-jackson

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the `Movie` class (instead of adding it to the comments) - it's very hard to read code from the comment section

Comment: You can parse out a list of them

Comment: @DeepeshkumarGupta  I added the movie class in the question.

Comment: @Albert Have you looked at the dupe?

Comment: I tried the solution at the duplicated @DaveNewton, the error is the question

Comment: @ShavkwithaHoon, I tried making another class, and I got a similar error.
Do you have any tutorial to parse out a list of them?

Comment: @Albert The list is at `items`, not at the root.